# The eventloop in JavaScript, why is there inconsistent behaviour in setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out why these two scripts behave different:

In the first case, I have a `setTimeout` of 10 miliseconds on the first function.

This makes sure my second function, which has a `setTimeout` of 0 miliseconds, to get executed first:

```js
setTimeout(()=> {
    for(var x = 0; x < 1000000000; x ++) {
        Math.pow(32, 13); // time consuming operation

        if (x == 999999999)
            console.log('bla')
    }
}, 10);


setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log('test')
}, 0);
```

In the seconds example, I have the exact same functions, but a `setTimeout` of 1 and 0, instead of 10 and 0.

Unlike the first snippet, where the timeout of 0 got executed first, the `setTimeout` of 0 actually waits for the `setTimeout` of 1 to be completely executed.

```js
setTimeout(()=> {
    for(var x = 0; x < 1000000000; x ++) {
        Math.pow(32, 13); // time consuming operation

        if (x == 999999999)
            console.log('bla')
    }
}, 1);


setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log('test')
}, 0);
```

This means the output of the first function is:

> test
>
> bla

While the second output is

> bla
>
> test

What causes this to happen?

Comment: I'd say it takes longer than 1ms to get to the 2nd setTimeout and, due to Javascript being single-threaded, you can't even create the 2nd timeout due to the first function still running.

Comment: Nothing *guarantees* when your functions will be executed. They'll only be executed *at least* x milliseconds in the future. Beyond that it's up to the scheduler to figure out when best to execute what. In the second case the difference between 1 and 0 is too short and the scheduler essentially needs to decide for both functions at the same time.

Comment: Essentially you've got a race condition, Javascript is (kinda) single threaded. So only one timeout will run at any one time with the other deffered till later. Which one will run first, well like the comment above says, that's up to the scheduler and times are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function has its delay value clamped, which means the 0 is ignored and set to a minimum value (usually 4ms or 10ms depending on the browser). Also, if the tab is inactive, the timeout may be delayed even further.

But when you give the `setTimeout` value 1, it will call it after 1ms. Javascript will not ignore value 1 in `setTimeout` but it can ignore 0.

`postMessage` is best way to use in place of `setTimeout` to 0.

One more thing when you are using this little difference of time (one value is zero), then sometime it execute the function according to the order of them in code.

For check you can put your `setTimeout` value 0 on before the `setTimeout` value 1 function. It will run `setTimeout` value 0 first then `setTimeout` value 1.

For reference of 4ms clamp detail you can check this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: It does not ignore 0, it will Move the function to the end of the call stack

Comment: Always yes. Then it start to call the second stack and execute functions according to given time. But it never consider 0 as time and will call the function on its minimum time, which can be 4ms to 10ms depending on the browser, or sometime less than 4ms its not fix.